# Set filter by partial string in mapbox-gl

Tags: javascript, json, mapbox-gl-js

My first question here, sorry in advance for any mistake...

I'm developing a mapbox web for my own pleasure, featuring photos taked by myself in a map. Info is loaded in JSON files, with this structure:

> ```
> "type": "Feature",
> "geometry": {
>   "type": "Point",
>   "coordinates": [-8.5375900268555,42.881175994873]
> },
> "properties": {
>   "title": "Graffiti",
>   "description": "",
>   "image": {
>       "imageSize": [1024, 768], "imageLandscape": 1, "imageUrl": "imgs/gsa_2016_files/20160805173018_OLY_PEP3_P8052307.jpg" },
>   "icon": {
>     "iconSize": [96, 73],
>     "iconUrl": "imgs/gsa_2016_files/thumb_20160805173018_OLY_PEP3_P8052307.jpg"
>   },
>   "extended_info": {
>     "tags": "graffitis,nomada",
>     "place": "europa,españa,galicia,santiago de compostela"
>   },
>   "time": "2016:08:05 17:30:18",
>   "year": 2016,
>   "month": 8,
>   "day": 5
> }
> ```
>
> }

I work with different JSON files for each map, which are loaded this way:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({ blah, blah... });

var layerIds = [ '2016' ];
var layerColors = [ 'rgba(255,0,0,1)' ];

function add_sources_to_map()
{
  for (var i = 0; i < layerIds.length; i++) {
    var id = layerIds[i]; 
    var layerId = layerIdPrefix + id;
    var geoJsonFile = 'jsons/'+ id + '.geoJSON';

    map.addSource(layerId, { type: 'geojson', data: geoJsonFile });
  }
}
```

Later on I use a function to filter elements by year:

```
function filterByYear(year) {
    var filterFullYear = [ '==', 'year', year];

    // Aplica os filtros nas capas
    for (var i = 0; i < layerIds.length; i++) {
        var id = layerIds[i];

        map.setFilter(id, filterFullYear);
    }
}
```

But I would like to do some more filtering, by part of tags or place content. For example, anyone with a "tag" which contains "nomada", or any "place" with "europe". I have tried to do it but failed miserably, although my knowledge of mapbox-gl or even js is limited. Can this be done? Should I change my JSON structure? Can anybody point me to some help?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in Mapbox-GL-JS. The issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4698